# ListBox within Popup - position and binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, wpf-controls

Following is the code of UI and code behind. There is no additional code than this.

Issues are

1. `ListBox` is not visible when I bind value to `ObservableCollection` with some delay.
2. `ListBox` is not in center of the popup. Can see in Design Viewer.

I tried placing `ListBox` out of popup and it works well. My need is to place listbox with in popup.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestWPF" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="600" 
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid x:Name="mainContainer">

        <Popup x:Name="popup" IsOpen="False" Margin="10" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainContainer}"
               Placement="Center" Height="300" Width="300">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding InstallationSummary}"> 
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" 
                            Margin="5" Padding="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> InstallationSummary;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

            InstallationSummary = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        async private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    InstallationSummary.Add("New Item-" + i);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting your private variable 
     ObservableCollection InstallationSummary 
to an public property like this

```
public ObservableCollection<string> InstallationSummary{ get set};
```

and should work fine..

Comment: Can you explain reason behind it? Will it work in MVVM pattern as well?

Comment: Reason behind is that Properties are used for data binding in XAML; fields just can't do it by itself since they do not implement getter and setter. As far as MVVM pattern is concerned.. just bind the datacontext of the xaml to the viewmodel and same result can be achieved with the MVVM pattern as well